# How to remove date

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a script to parse some reports. At the end of each page there is the date, when they were printed, in this format:

```
Printed on Jun 12, 2012 at 10:04 PM
```

I want to remove that text but since my regex knowledge is very basic, I have no idea how to proceed. It should also cover the AM/PM. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to remove it completely?

Comment: How are you parsing the reports?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the date completely. But the date on the reports is always different, so i cant hardcode it.
I'm using php string functions to parse them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('~Printed on.*?(AM|PM)~', '', $text);
```

It will remove everything from "Printed on" up to AM or PM